# How to view my system-wide policies in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, restrictions

I was just wondering how to view the system-wide policies for my managed computer, such as network, website restrictions, allowed applications, etc. I know that in Edge I can view them by going to `edge://policy`, but how do I view the system-wide policies? I am using Windows 11.

---

**UPDATE**: I *think* I have found that the files `gpedit.msc` and `secpol.msc` show the policies, but I can't open them because it is blocked (obviously). I opened them in Notepad, but they are a mess of code and random characters.

How would I decode these files and figure out what they mean? I have attached the files below:

[gpedit.msc](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqLNF_maaUCtgu9vU9zBX5F3dF69SA?e=Ba3Yde)

[secpol.msc](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqLNF_maaUCtgu9wvAs2xLtAQdUyhA?e=087Ior)

Comment: I just figured out that the policies are in gpedit.msc and secpol.msc. I can't open those files because it is blocked (obviously) but I opened them in Notepad, and I got a mess of code and random characters. How would I decode these files? I can send them if you guys want.

Comment: gpedit and secpol are just viewers, they do not store the policies themselves but reference definition files stored on the domain controller and settings applied in your computer's registry. The Resultant Set Of Policy tool is the official means for viewing a summary of policies applied to your computer using Group Policy. Otherwise, digging through the registry manually is your other option, but that is practically impossible.

Comment: That said: the correct thing to do, because the computer you are using does not belong to you but to your employer, is to speak with the team(s) your employer has designated responsible for managing your computer. Questions about computer equipment owned by a company are GENERALLY off topic here. IT staff can and do ask questions here, because they are the people responsible for managing the computers. But line staff really should go to their IT staff.

Comment: I have attached regedit.msc and secpol.msc to my question, could somebody please help me decode those files?

Comment: I already explained that those files are not themselves collections of policies. Please read the instructions that have been given already, and speak with your IT staff. Like the other things you've referenced already Regedit is just a utility for viewing and modifying the registry hives, which are stored elsewhere.

Comment: @music2myear Can I find where those policies are  on my computer using the information in those files? So I can then open and view the actual policies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149731/discussion-between-enderman-and-music2myear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the computer is being managed, as there are many different approaches to managing computers in a corporate environment.

The most common ones for windows can be viewed like so:

- **Active Directory Group Policies (Windows Domain):** You can view all the applied policy items in a similar way to the `edge://policy` page by running the command `gpresult /h "C:\temp\gpresult.html"` and opening that html file. Note that you need to run it as administrator to read and report on system-level policies. You can still look in the registry (most of them are show up under `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\`), but that's much less readable.
- **Microsoft Intune/MDM policies** (365 domain-joined device): Can export detailed policy information using `mdmdiagnosticstool.exe -area "DeviceEnrollment;DeviceProvisioning;Autopilot" -zip "c:\temp\MDMDiagReport.zip"` for example. Unzip the resulting file, and open `MDMDiagHtmlReport.html` in a browser to see the policies.

---

That said, many/most corporate environments use additional third-party software for managing web restrictions, software and network access, etc.

Comment: Hey, do you know how to find the file locations of the policies using gpedit.msc and secpol.msc?

Comment: @Enderman The default file location for AD GPOs is like `"\\CompanyDomain.com\sysvol\Policies\[long-guid]\"`. They are not useful, since the actual setting names and descriptions are stored in templates elsewhere (for different languages). `gpedit.msc` only looks at locally-managed settings (stored in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\GroupPolicy\ `). To view AD policies, you need the `gpmc.msc` tool instead (not installed by default).

Comment: How would you get the gpmc.msc tool? Can you download it from somewhere?

Comment: @Enderman look up how to install RSAT (remote server administration tools).